# Show Div When Click Check-box Radio

Tags: html, css, button, checkbox, radio-button

As you can see in the title I want to show Divs related to my check-box radio button. I looked for past topics about that and I try to do it with some scripts but I failed. I know Im missing somethings.

What I want to do is; when click on Second button (check-box radio tool 2) I want to open div class row3. and When click on First button (check-box radio tool 1) I want to open div class row2.

Maybe it is so easy but Im new on this stuffs. Any help or sugestion would be great.

Thanks..

```css
/* PRODUCTS AND BUTTONS */

.button {
    position: absolute;
bottom: 0%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #d8d8d8cc;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-size: 70%;
width: 70%;
height: 20%;;

border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 7px;
text-align: center;
  }

  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;



  }

  .container2 {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
}

.container2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.container2 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
}



.column2 {
float: center;
width: 2300%;
padding:8px;
}





.row2 {

width: 80%;
padding:5px;
position: relative;
left: 23%;
bottom: 5%;
margin-top:5%;


}
/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row2::after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}

.row3 {

    width: 80%;
    padding:5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 23%;
    bottom: 5%;
    margin-top:5%;
    
    
    }
    /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
    .row3::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    }

*:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}


/* PRODUCTS AND BUTTONS END */






/* Split the screen in half */
.split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  /* Control the left side */
  .left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  }
  
  /* Control the right side */
  .right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  
  /* If you want the content centered horizontally and vertically */
  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .centered2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  /* Style the image inside the centered container, if needed */
  .centered img {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }








/* Please ❤ this if you like it! */


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&subset=devanagari,latin-ext');


:root {
    --white: #ffffff;
    --light: #f0eff3;
    --black: #000000;
    --dark-blue: #ffffff;
    --dark-light: #ffffff;
    --red: #d8d8d8;
    --yellow: #d8d8d8;
    --grey: #ecedf3;
}

/* #Primary
================================================== */

body{
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dark-blue);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
p{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: var(--white);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
::selection {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}
::-moz-selection {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}
mark{
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    
    

}
.over-hide {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.z-bigger {
    z-index: 100 !important;
}


.background-color{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .background-color{
    background-color: var(--white);
}


[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked){
    position: absolute;

    left: -9999px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox:checked + label,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label{
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 17px 0;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(298deg, var(--red), var(--yellow));
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'unicons';
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 17px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content: '\eac1';
    left: 0;
    color: var(--grey);
    background-color: var(--dark-light);

}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
    content: '\eb8f';
    left: 30px;
    color: var(--yellow);
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);

}

.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 p{
    color: var(--dark-blue);
}


.checkbox-tools:checked + label,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
    position: relative;

    padding: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--white);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
    background-color: var(--dark-light);

}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label{
    background-color: transparent;

}
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label::before,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(298deg, var(--red), var(--yellow));
    z-index: -1;
}
.checkbox-tools:checked + label .uil,
.checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label .uil{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 .checkbox-tools:not(:checked) + label{
    background-color: var(--light);
    color: var(--dark-blue);
    box-shadow: 0 1x 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.checkbox-budget:checked + label,
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 260px;
    font-size: 52px;
    line-height: 52px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px var(--white);
    text-stroke: 1px var(--white);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label{
    background-color: var(--dark-light);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.checkbox-budget:checked + label{
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.checkbox-budget:checked + label::before,
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(138deg, var(--red), var(--yellow));
    z-index: -1;
}
.checkbox-budget:checked + label span,
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label span{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.checkbox-budget:checked + label span::before,
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label span::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-text-stroke: transparent;
    text-stroke: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: var(--white);
    text-fill-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--white);
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
    transition: max-height 0.3s;
}
.checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label span::before{
    max-height: 0;
}
.checkbox-budget:checked + label span::before{
    max-height: 100%;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-xl-10 .checkbox-budget:not(:checked) + label{
    background-color: var(--light);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px var(--dark-blue);
    text-stroke: 1px var(--dark-blue);
    box-shadow: 0 1x 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.checkbox-booking:checked + label,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label{
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 6px 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--white);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: var(--dark-light);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label::before{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label::before{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label:hover::before{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label::before,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: -2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(138deg, var(--red), var(--yellow));
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label::before{
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label::after,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: -2;
    background-color: var(--dark-light);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label::after{
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label .uil,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label .uil{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label .text,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label .text{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms linear;
    transition: opacity 300ms linear;
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label .text{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label .text::after,
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label .text::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 2px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(138deg, var(--red), var(--yellow));
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}
.checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label .text::after{
    width: 0;
}
.checkbox-booking:checked + label .text::after{
    width: 100%;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 .checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label,
.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 .checkbox-booking:checked + label{
    background-color: var(--light);
    color: var(--dark-blue);
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 .checkbox-booking:checked + label::after,
.checkbox:checked ~ .section .container .row .col-12 .checkbox-booking:not(:checked) + label::after{
    background-color: var(--light);
}




.link-to-page {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 20000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
}
.link-to-page img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.js" />
 
    <title>REXIN 3D-AR DEMO</title>


    <style>

    </style>

</head>


<body>


  <div class="split left">

  </div>
    
   
  <div class="split right">

  
   <div class="centered2">   
     <div class="section over-hide z-bigger">
       <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="general" id="general">
         <div class="section over-hide z-bigger">
           <div class="container pb-5">
              <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5">

                <div class="col-12 pb-5">

                 <input class="checkbox-tools" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-1" checked>
                 <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="tool-1">           
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
                 </label>
                 <br>

                 <input class="checkbox-tools" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-2">
                 <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="tool-2">
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
                 </label>
                 <br>

                 <input class="checkbox-tools" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-3">
                 <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="tool-3">           
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
                 </label>
                 <br>

                 <input class="checkbox-tools" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-4">
                 <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="tool-4">  
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
                 </label>
                 <br>


                 <input class="checkbox-tools" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-5">
                 <label class="for-checkbox-tools" for="tool-5">
                 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Location_dot_black.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
                 </label>

                </div>
                
              </div>    
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row2">

      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/terrassen.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="terrassendach.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Terrassendach </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
                 
      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/pergolen.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="pergolen.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Pergolen </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/carport.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="carport.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Carport </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
                     
      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/Vordächer.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="vordacher.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Vordächer </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
 
    </div>



    <div class="row3">

      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/terrassen.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="terrassendach.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Terrassendach </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
                 
      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/pergolen.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="pergolen.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Pergolen </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/carport.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="carport.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Carport </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
                     
      <div class="column2">
      <div class="container2">
      <img src="Assets/photos/Vordächer.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
      <a href="vordacher.html"> <button class="button" style="vertical-align:top">
      <span>Vordächer </span></button></a>
      </div>
      </div>
 
    </div>


  </div>
          
          
 

</body>
```

Comment: If the divs are not children of the radio button you will probably need javascript. What have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5hhCQ/ I've tried this one. If it is possible can you show how to integrate it to my codes.

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php I've tried this one and got it! Now It working. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this! (Run code snippet to see)

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/dhanushbadge/pen/kICBu

Made by: @Dhanush Badge

```js
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
}
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>How many check boxes do you want when clicked on a radio button?</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" />
None
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" />
Two
<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr><p>Okay Cool! Here are those two...</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="one">
One &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="two">
Two
</div>
```